# CustomControl Slide Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

Due to other reasons I need **WPF CustomControl**. My goal is **Slide Window**, that has property **IsActive**.

If this property is changed to true, then the Slide Window slide in from left to right. If this property is changed back from true, then the SlideWindow slide out.

This functionality works fine (I do that by **triggers** in **XAML** file). I need also set **visibility** to **Visibile** (before slide in effect starts) or **Collapsed** (after slide out effect finished). And that is the problem.

---

**SlideWindowControl.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SlideWindowTest
{
    public class SlideWindowControl : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "IsActive", typeof(Boolean), typeof(SlideWindowControl), new PropertyMetadata(true));

        static SlideWindowControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SlideWindowControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SlideWindowControl)));
        }

        public Boolean IsActive
        {
            get { return (Boolean)GetValue(IsActiveProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Corresponding **Generic.xaml** for **SlideWindowControl**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlideWindowTest">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SlideWindowControl}">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SlideWindowControl}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            x:Name="Root">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid Background="Black">
                                <TextBlock Text="HEADER" Foreground="White" Margin="17" FontSize="20pt" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="True">

                            <!-- Show -->
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- Visibility change cause trouble
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0" BeginTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        -->

                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>

                            <!-- Hide -->
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5"/>

                                        <!-- Visibility change cause trouble
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0" BeginTime="0:00:00.5">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        -->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

Example of use **SlideWindowControl** in **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SlideWindowTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlideWindowTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Slide In" Click="SlideInButton_Click"/> <!-- InMainWindow.xaml.cs set MySlideWindow.IsActive = true; -->
            <Button Content="Slide Out" Click="SlideOutButton_Click" /> <!-- InMainWindow.xaml.cs set MySlideWindow.IsActive = false; -->
        </StackPanel>

        <local:SlideWindowControl x:Name="MySlideWindow">
            <TextBlock FontSize="40pt">Super Content!</TextBlock>
        </local:SlideWindowControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

I try set **Visibility Property** also in triggers in **Generic.xaml** for **SlideWindowControl** (see in commented code please), but it breaks whole trigger (no animation effect is shown).

How can I achieve change of **Visibility Property**? I need to bind to **Visibility Property** in other components.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be:

1. Create the two storyboards as Static Resources and reference them in the BeginStoryboard-Storyboard ({StaticResource SlideIn}) instead of having them as inline children.
2. Implement their Completed event
3. In the Completed-eventhandler you set the Visibility to Collapsed when IsActive = false.
4. In the FadeIn-click event, you'll have to set the Visibility to Visible before you set IsActive = true.

This is a little asymmetric but it works in my test case.

```
    <Window x:Class="SO38699140.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO38699140"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideIn" Completed="Storyboard_Completed" >
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="0" Duration="0:00:00.5"  />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideOut" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:00:00.5" />
    </Storyboard>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SlideWindowControl}">
      <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SlideWindowControl}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            x:Name="Root">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid Background="Black">
                  <TextBlock Text="HEADER" Foreground="White" Margin="17" FontSize="20pt" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter />
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="True">

                <!-- Show -->
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideIn}">
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>

                <!-- Hide -->
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideOut}">
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Slide In" Click="SlideInButton_Click"/>
        <!-- InMainWindow.xaml.cs set MySlideWindow.IsActive = true; -->
        <Button Content="Slide Out" Click="SlideOutButton_Click" />
        <!-- InMainWindow.xaml.cs set MySlideWindow.IsActive = false; -->
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MySlideWindow, Path=Visibility}" />

    </StackPanel>

      <local:SlideWindowControl x:Name="MySlideWindow">
        <TextBlock FontSize="40pt">Super Content!</TextBlock>
      </local:SlideWindowControl>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

        }

    private void SlideInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MySlideWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      MySlideWindow.IsActive = true;
    }

    private void SlideOutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MySlideWindow.IsActive = false;
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!MySlideWindow.IsActive)
        MySlideWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
```